# javascript - How can I wait for asyncronous loop in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am making a private messaging system with Node.js and socket.io.
I need to send the latest messages between 2 users. Separately both `get_messages_between_users` function and `get_message_user` functions works fine. But If I use them like below, `messages` array is staying empty when socket emits the data. It is normal actually due to asynchronous structure of Javascript but how can I solve this problem?
Here is the code.

```
function get_message_user(message, callback) {
    var sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE id = " + message.from_user
    var query = dbh.query(sql, function(err, result) {
        callback(message, result[0]);
    });
};

function get_messages_between_users(user1, user2, callback) {
    var sql = "SELECT id, from_user, to_user, content, msg_date, status FROM messages WHERE ((to_user = "+user1+" AND from_user = "+user2+") OR (to_user = "+user2+" AND from_user = "+user1+")) ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 20;"
    var query = dbh.query(sql, function(err, result) {
        callback(result);
    });
};

io.on('connection',function (socket) {
    //Other stuff for handling clients
    socket.on("page messages", function (data) {
        var messages = [];
        get_messages_between_users(socket.session.user_id, data.to_user, function(result){
            for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
                get_message_user(result[i], function(message, user){
                    var obj = {id: message.id, user_id: user.id, username: user.username, avatar:user.avatar_url, content: message.content, msg_date:message.msg_date};
                    messages.push(obj);
                });
            }
        });

        //The problem is messages array is empty here.
        socket.emit('message history', JSON.stringify(messages));
    });
});
```

I am using `message` parameter in `get_message_user` just for bypassing variable to result.

Comment: FYI, you're wide open to SQL injection attacks and related flaws.  Never concatenate arbitrary data into a query.  Bind parameters instead!

Comment: I am aware of that. I just wanted to make everything work then I will make necessary improvements.

Comment: That's really unfortunate, that rather than building this correctly, you're actually taking extra time to make a less reliable and more insecure application.  A `for...of` loop is what you want, with `await`.

Comment: Actually you are right, but I am learning now, this won't be in production soon. Can you show me some pseudo-code about your concept?

Comment: I don't know what DB library you're using, but normally you'd do something like `const query = db.bind('SELECT * FROM whatever WHERE field=?;')`.  And then, something like `query.execute(['value for the field']);`.  As for the async loop:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of

Comment: I mean not for data binding probably there are tons of examples out there. But I couldn't understand your logic with `for...of loop` and `await`.

Comment: Hey, @kenarsuleyman. I am setting an example here: https://repl.it/@kostasx1/StackOverflow-59349803

Can you check the code on your environment, as I don't have access to the database library you are using?

Comment: @KostasX I am fascinated. It works perfectly. The problem is I don't even know what Promise is. I have to find a Udemy course about that. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: @Brad I am a security engineer. My job is to prevent this stuff. IMO, it is fine to have imperfect, insecure code as a prototype as long as you fix it before going to prod. Make it work, make it beautiful &secure, make it fast - in that order

Comment: @kenarsuleyman Welcome to the fascinating Asynchronous world of JavaScript! In order to master JS/Node, you must dive into asynchronous programming. In my answer I have included some links to get you started. Promises and Async/Await is a **must** if you are going to write JS.

Comment: Also, take care of validating/escaping the users' input before placing them as data to your DB queries, as correctly @Brad has pointed out. Do not start by overlooking these issues, as it will become a (bad) habit.

Comment: @DanPantry The issue here isn't a matter of completeness, such as it would be for prototype code.  It's that this method of assembling queries is fundamentally flawed.  Frankly, I'm shocked that you as a security engineer would find this acceptable.  Besides, concatenating data into a query isn't even easier, or faster for slapping together a test or anything.  It's simply flat out broken, and never ending because people learning are taught that this is how you begin.  That's simply wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a couple of things in order to refactor your code to handle all these asynchronous operations which depend on each other:

1) Convert the `get_message_user` and `get_messages_between_users` functions into Promise-based functions.

*(**Note**: as suggested in the comments below, the optimal solution would be to use the promise-based functions supported by the current database library or switch to one that uses Promises for these operations. Alternatively a utility can be used to easily turn the callback functions into Promise-based functions. One such utility is [Promisify](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original)*

2) Convert the `socket.on("page message")` callback into an async function

3) Inside the socket callback, call the `get_messages_between_users` function and `await` for the async result

4) Once the result list is returned, loop over it and create an array of calls to the `get_message_user` async function and `await` for the result of all these async requests using the `Promise.all()` function.

5) Once the results are returned, map (or loop) over them, and add the data to the messages array and emit the data via the `socket.emit` function

```js
function get_message_user(message) {
    // Return a Promise that will be handled via a then() method
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        let sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE id = " + message.from_user;
        dbh.query(sql, function(err, result) {
            if ( err ){ reject(err); } // Handle Error via a catch() method
            resolve([message,result[0]]);
        });
    })
};

function get_messages_between_users(user1, user2) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        let sql = "SELECT id, from_user, to_user, content, msg_date, status FROM messages WHERE ((to_user = "+user1+" AND from_user = "+user2+") OR (to_user = "+user2+" AND from_user = "+user1+")) ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 20;"
        dbh.query(sql, function(err, result) {
            if ( err ){ reject(err); }
            resolve(result);
        });
    })
};

io.on('connection',function (socket) {

    // We need an async function here, in order to use await on async operations
    socket.on("page messages", async function (data) {

        let messages = [];
        // Wait for the asynchronous operation to give back a result using await
        const result = await get_messages_between_users(socket.session.user_id, data.to_user);
        const requests = []; // This will hold a list of async requests for each result
        for ( let i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
            requests.push( get_message_user(result[i]) );
        }
        const results = await Promise.all(requests);
        results.map((result)=>{
            let message = result[0];
            let user = result[1];
            let obj = {
              id: message.id,
              user_id: user.id,
              username: user.username,
              avatar:user.avatar_url,
              content: message.content,
              msg_date:message.msg_date
            };
            messages.push(obj);
        });

        socket.emit('message history', JSON.stringify(messages));

    });

});
```

**References:**

- [Promises](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises)
- [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)
- [Async/Await](https://javascript.info/async-await)

*Note*: no need to pay for a Udemy course. You can check these excellent courses on asynchronous programming in Udacity:

- [Asynchronous JavaScript Requests](https://www.udacity.com/course/asynchronous-javascript-requests--ud109)
- [JavaScript Promises](https://www.udacity.com/course/javascript-promises--ud898)

**Warning**: As correctly pointed out by the comments above, the code that handles the SQL queries posted in the question needs some heavy refactoring in order for the code to be secure. The code in this answer is provided only to demonstrate how one might handle multiple asynchronous requests. The rest of the code remains **insecure** and **must** be refactored.

Comment: FYI, it would be best for the OP to just USE the promise interface built into their database rather than create their own.  If this is mysql, then that can be found in [msyql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2).  Lots and lots and lots of good reasons to be moving entirely to promises for asynchronous work anyway.

Comment: You are right @jfriend00. I was thinking about that, but since I didn't know which library was used I decided to post the example above. I will update the answer with your suggestion. Thanks.